# VBA Code works with button but doesn't work with shortcut

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Sheet (destination.xlsm) where I want to import data from another sheet (source.xlsm).

- I let the user select the source file using GetOpenFilenames.
- I open the file selected
- I copy some range from the selected file and paste it to the destination file (in which there is a module where this code is stored.)

Issue:

- Code works when I call the Sub using F5 or Run button inside the VBA editor. Code also works if I create a button and assign this macro to the button on the worksheet. **However, when I assign the macro a keyboard shortcut from Macro Manager in Excel, then the code stops after opening the source file.** All operations after that are not done.
- Again if I debug the code and run it in steps (F8), then again everything works fine.

Sample Code:

```
Sub sample_code()

Dim file as Variant
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files(*.xlsm*),*.xlsm*")
Dim oBook as Workbook
Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
Dim oSheet as Worksheet
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("List")

'*Code to copy some range from oSheet and paste it to a sheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("ConsolidatedList")*

End Sub
```

What could be the issue here? How should I proceed with this issue?

Comment: Assuming the macro is in a standard module, assigning a macro shortcut with [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) is a breeze: just add `'@ExcelHotkey K` as a comment just above the macro, then look for "missing attribute" inspection result and select "adjust attribute values" to have Ctrl+Shift+K run that macro. Or use a small k to assign a shortcut without the Shift key. And then if the hidden attribute somehow gets lost again, Rubberduck inspections will tell you

Comment: Have you consider appending it into a button within a worksheet? Or build a ribbon for it using [custom UI editor](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm) for office? I know it may not be what you're looking for, but I've found out that having elements visible for user interaction it's more friendly than shortcuts.

Comment: Your code works as is for me when the macro is run, called from a button or from the Quick Access Toolbar but is not visible to choose for a keyboard shortcut using Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2211 Build 16.0.15831.20098) 64 bit

Comment: Assign the macro to ctrl-K and, exactly as you say, stops after opening the file. On the second run through it works fine. From the keyboard the macro is called by pressing shift-ctrl-K.

Comment: are you sure the opened workbook will always have a worksheet named after "List"?

Comment: Problem may be here: `Code to copy some range from oSheet and paste it to a sheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("ConsolidatedList")`

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342606/vba-code-works-in-macro-but-not-on-a-button?rq=1

Comment: You wrote : _the code stops after opening the source file_. Did you mean the code show an error message with END - DEBUG button ? and when you click the DEBUG button, the yellow line is on `Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("List")` ?

Comment: Does the workbook handle workbook/worksheet events? Try turning them off before copying the sheet if that's the case.

Comment: I cannot add a button or assign it to a ribbon button or anything like that. I do not wish to show this macro to the end user. Only that I want to execute the macro through a keyboard shortcut. Figures, I can't open an external excel file to import while using SHIFT in the shortcut.

Comment: @karma No. It just stops abruptly without any message.

Comment: Will check @user10186832 suggestion and revert.

Comment: Show the rest of the code where the copy is made, as maybe the problem is there